# Where do I find the default html page of Apache tomcat for 400 error codes?

Tags: tomcat

I had noticed that the default error page shown by tomcat has server information,which I want it to be suppressed, Hence I thought of checking out on that default file ,which I'm unable to get the location!!! Anyone knows about it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat by default does not have configuration for 400 error pages. It is done through your web application. Most likely some where in `web.xml` you can find below mapping

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>**/error.html**</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Also is there any other way to handle this error codes,.. other than creating a custom error page,!!  like <error-page></error-page>

Comment: if tomcat does not provide default error page,how is it that the error page is shown,even when user has not configured it!!!???

Comment: Well, tomcat has some default handlers. But instead of looking for them in order to change them (that's what I'm expecting to be the background of your question), just use @Yogesh's suggestion and provide your own error page. If you don't do that, the assumption is that you're probably happy with the default you get.

Comment: After adding the custom error page,Do I have to change any tomcat config?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
                   showReport="false"
                   showServerInfo="false" />
```

under , in server.xml file of tomcat.
This disables the default error page ,instead just shows "HTTP ERROR -{{code}}"